# How do I unbind beforePopState binding in Next.js router?

Tags: javascript, next.js

I am using Next.js. Suppose I bound something useing `Router.beforePopState`:

```js
Router.beforePopState(() => {
  // Do something
});
```

Suppose I don't need to listen to this event anymore at some point. How do I "off" the event handler?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It's not really an event it's just a callback to get ride of it try

```
Router.beforePopState(() => true);
```

or just

```
Router.beforePopState()
```